# How would I clean this data set to be used with weka from tableau?

Tags: algorithm, csv, weka, data-mining, tableau-api

The first thing I noticed was that weka only accepts CSV. So should there be an easy way to convert the tableau data to csv format?

Month:1
Day:1
Hour:1
Minute:1

THe Excel format doesn't allow date/time so I seem to run into some errors. Would all data mining concepts include this kind of data cleaning from tableau to weka?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your objective.

There is no general rule how data must be preprocessed, or there would be a "automatic preprocessing" button.

I cannot imagine what task you could solve with hour, minute, second columns that would warrant the use of Weka or data mining; and that cannot be done more reliably with simpler tools.

Comment: It can, but that's the point is to try the small formatting stuff: I am not arguing with your assumption because I did the exact same thing in python.

Comment: Would there be any formats or specifications that would make tabelau and weka easy to use?
My problem exactly the null spaces when I do a graph. So would I have to add null items or just stick with columns only?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "null spaces when I do a graph", and your question remains unanswerable because we don't know your objective, what your data is good for, and what you attempt to do.